# What is Spiritualism means in Hinduism?

Tags: spirituality

Spiritualism is commonly referred as a practice of specific religious thoughts and belief in afterlife or spirits. Basically, the word spiritualism has no specific definition as it’s meaning differs from person to person, place to place and religion to religion. But where ever we go; we can discover that spiritualism is superior than any other religion and it’s basic principle stands with three mighty words (truth, faith, and belief).

"How can I describe Spiritualism in Hinduism?"

Comment: Spiritualism is an ambiguous Western concept. It has some popularity with Western 'new age' adherents which tries to mix various beliefs from different religious traditions resulting in an incoherent mix of beliefs. It has no foundations in Hinduism or even in Western philosophical traditions.

Comment: Your blog already has an answer. Do you expect a better answer from our site? P.S I am not the down voter.

Comment: This is a very very vague question IMO

Answer (score 1):

**Hinduism is all about Spiritualism.**

The question should be what is the way of mukti in Hinduism ?
However spirituality means looking and studying inwards, the answer could be very vast but I will try to give you an overview, **by practicing good karmas** one has to attain purity of intellect and mind, which result in tranquility, at last **one can attain Moksha** or Mukti (Ultimate Freedom).

So what should we learn from this Question is that **Karma which start from thought**, if you think good , you will do good, hence Good karmas and we should try to remain conscious and also every karma has to be done towards God, not for self, but we all are looking outwards and finding other people mistakes.

So instead of finding other people mistakes because **Hinduism is the only religion where you are free to do prayer in your own way**, if you want to worship a river, stone, mountain, tree, chair, table etc. You are welcome just do it as deep as you can, Bharam is Omnipresent